# How do i decode and get string values from json

Tags: php, html, json

How do i get the string output? There is one error which occurred when i tried to decode. And I want to insert the output value in textbox.

How can it be done ?

```
$array=json_decode($json); 
echo $array;

**Warning:**
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\school\vijay\update.php on line 20
```

My php

```
<?php
$json = array();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","school","certify");

$db_select = mysql_select_db('School_Data', $con);
$childid = $_GET['childid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM childinfo where ChildID='$childid'",$con);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[] = $r;
}
if($result){
echo json_encode($json);
}
else 
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

//$obj = unserialize($json);
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($json);
echo $arrayOfEmails;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My JSON Output

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "ChildID": "1001",
    "ParentID": "2002",
    "SiblingsID": "hfh",
    "TeacherID": "hfhf",
    "ChildName": "fhfh",
    "DOB": "2014-03-04",
    "Age": "0",
    "Gender": "male",
    "Grade": "KG1",
    "Section": "KG1",
    "Stream": "NORMAL",
    "BloodGroup": "O-",
    "Nationality": "KG1",
    "Country": "Lebanon",
    "Religion": "KG1",
    "MotherTongue": "KG1",
    "FirstLanguage": "bfbf",
    "SecondLanguage": "fbfbfb",
    "PlaceOfBirth": "fhfh",
    "LandlineNumber": "0",
    "EmailID": "dgdgd@gg.c",
    "ChildPhoto": "Requirement.PNG",
    "TemporaryAddress": "bfdbd",
    "PermanentAddress": "bdbdbf",
    "Mentor": "fbbfd",
    "DateOfJoin": "2014-03-06",
    "JoinGrade": "J",
    "ReferredBy": "bdbf",
    "ContactNumber": "0",
    "EmergencyContactNumber": "0"
}]
```

Comment: `$arrayOfEmails` is an object and you can't directly `echo` it out.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Then how can i get the respective outputs in textbox

Comment: i need to display the jason values in html form

Comment: Hold on there a minute. How exactly do you propose that both json_encode and json_decode would function if passed the exact same piece of data? You call each function with `$json` as the input. Uh-uh, not quite sensible. Call json_decode with the _result_ of a call to json_encode.

Comment: New version that is complete. Should help you to get going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the json encoded array then restore it later.

untested code

```
<?php
$json = array();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","school","certify");

$db_select = mysql_select_db('School_Data', $con);
$childid = $_GET['childid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM childinfo where ChildID='$childid'",$con);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[] = $r;
}
if($result){
$encodedJson = json_encode($json); // save json string for later
echo $encodedJson;
}
else 
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

//$obj = unserialize($json);
$arrayOfEmails = json_decode($encodedJson); // convert back to an array
var_dump($arrayOfEmails);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: i can get values from json as per your code.how to display those values in corresponding html field

Comment: i can get values.but i need to show these values in respective html form

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely different beast to answer the full question asked. Rather more work than i initially planned (about 5 hours). Still it does the job rather nicely, imo.

I have converted it to PDO. Even 'mysqli' was rather more limiting that i wanted.

Purpose: select child details from the db. Shows a form with all the details. Validates the input - well, checks for missing input. Displays individual error messages. Have a play with it.

It needs version 5.3 'cos i use a 'closure' in it. That can be changed for a function if required. Just let me know.

Tested: PHP 5.3.18, mysql 5.5 windows xp (oi, stop laffin')

```
<?php // Q22732117

/*
 * As i provide the database code you will have to change your current code to
 * either 'mysqli' or 'PDO'.
 *
 * 'cos the update statements are easier with PDO that is what i shall use!'
 *
 * needs PHP version 5.3 or greater
 *
 * contact me if you are on an earlier version
 */

/*
 *  database connection...
 */
$myDatabaseName = 'School_Data';
$username = 'school';
$password = 'certify';

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$myDatabaseName}";
$options = array(    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
$theDB = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$theDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/*
 * get the child info into the 'currentChildInfo' array no need to use JSON...
 */
$childid = !empty($_GET['childid']) ? $_GET['childid'] : '';

/*
 * get child details
 */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM childinfo where ChildID = :childid";

$query = $theDB->prepare($sql);

$query->execute(array(':childid' => $childid));

$resultSet = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (empty($resultSet)) {
    die("One of our children ($childid) is missing!");
}

/*
 * current child info for use throughout the script
 *
 * We need to keep a copy of this so we can check which fields are being updated.
 */
$originalChildInfo = current($resultSet);
$currentChildInfo =  current($resultSet);

/*
 *  these data items will be hidden fields on the form
 */
$hiddenFields = array(
    "ID", "ChildID", "ParentID", "SiblingsID", "TeacherID"
    );


// -------------------------
$allInformationIsCorrect = true;  // need this to halt script correctly

if (!empty($_POST['goForIt'])) { // process the input...

    $errorMsgs = array(); // hold individual error messages in here
                          // so you can display them in the HTML later!

    /*
     * transfer the $_POST data to the array...
     */
    foreach($_POST['childInfo'] as $itemName => $itemValue ) {
        $currentChildInfo[$itemName] = $itemValue;
    }

    /*
     * Validate all the input
     */
    foreach($currentChildInfo as $itemName => $itemValue ) {

        // ignore hidden fields...
        if (in_array($itemName, $hiddenFields)) {
            continue; // ignore and do nest one
        }

        // check for missing data
        if (empty($currentChildInfo[$itemName])) {
            $errorMsgs[$itemName] = 'Oi! you missed some!!!';
            continue;
        }

        // extra validation here...

    }
    $allInformationIsCorrect =  empty($errorMsgs); // any errors?

    /*
     *  update the database?
     */
    if ($allInformationIsCorrect) { // update the database

        /*
         * get list of columns to update
         */
        $updateColumns = array_uintersect_assoc($currentChildInfo,
                                                $originalChildInfo,
                                                function ($value1, $value2) {
                                                  if ($value1 === $value2) {
                                                      return 1;
                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                      return 0;
                                                  }
                                                });

        $sqlColumns  = '';
        $boundValues = array();

         foreach($updateColumns as $itemName => $itemValue ) {
            // ignore hidden fields...
            if (in_array($itemName, $hiddenFields)) {
                continue; // ignore and do next one
            }

            $_colName  = '`'. $itemName .'`';
            $_bindName = ':'. $itemName .'';

            $sqlColumns .= "$_colName = $_bindName,";

            $boundValues[$_bindName] = $itemValue;
        }
        $sqlColumns  = rtrim($sqlColumns, ', '); // lose trailing comma


        // generate the sql 'where' clause
        $sqlWhere = " where `ChildID` = :ChildID";
        $boundValues[':ChildID'] = $currentChildInfo['ChildID'];

        try {
            if (!empty($sqlColumns)) { // skip if nothing changed
                $sql =   "update childinfo  set "
                       . $sqlColumns
                       . $sqlWhere;
                $query = $theDB->prepare($sql);
                $allOk = $query->execute($boundValues);
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo 'drat! '. $e->getMessage();
            // throw $e; // re-raise the exception
        }
    }
}

// if all ok then leave else show the form for corrections
if (!empty($_POST['goForIt']) && $allInformationIsCorrect) {
  echo 'all done, we are going home! <br />';
  exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Amend Child Information.</title>
   <style type="text/css">
       .item {
           margin: 2px;
           border: 1px wheat dotted;
       }
    .item-name {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        text-align: right;
        margin: 2px;
        padding-right: 3px;
        border-top: 1px  #adadad dotted;
        background-color: wheat ;
    }
    .item-value {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 35%;
        text-align: left;
        background-color:  wheat;
    }
    .item-error {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 38%;
        text-align: left;
        background-color:  #eea236;
    }
   </style>
</head>

  <body>
    <h2>Child data</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset >
            <legend>Current Child Information</legend>
        <?php foreach($currentChildInfo as $itemName => $itemValue ): ?>
           <?php $isHidden = false; // need this to sort out whether to print a closing 'div' '?>
           <?php if (in_array($itemName, $hiddenFields)):  // create a hidden field ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="childInfo[<?= $itemName ?>]" value="<?= $itemValue ?>">
                <?php $isHidden = true; ?>
           <?php else: ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <label for="<?= $itemName ?>" class="item-name" id="<?= $itemName ?>"><?= trim($itemName), '&nbsp:' ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="childInfo[<?= $itemName ?>]" id="<?= $itemName ?>"
                           value="<?= $itemValue ?>"
                           class="item-value">
           <?php endif; ?>

           <?php if (!empty($errorMsgs[$itemName]) && !$isHidden): // show the error message ?>
                <div class="item-error">
                    <?= $errorMsgs[$itemName] ?>
                </div>
               </div> <!-- close item div -->

           <?php elseif (!$isHidden): ?>
               </div> <!-- close item div -->

           <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="goForIt" value="Go For It!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i get:One of our children () is missing!.what is the pupose to display  it

Comment: Look at where the error message came from. There was no rows returned from the query. Either you didn't pass a childid to the script or the childid was not found on the database. Feel free to edit the script any way that you want. The code is not designed to be complete. It is now **your** code. Do what you wish with it. Change all the error message etc. I will help you fix bugs that you find. It not working the way you want is not a fault. :-) I will try and help you to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Here is a tutorial about 'mysqli' that explains enough about it. I used the 'prepared statement' stuff. **['MySQLi' for Beginners](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)**. If you want to see what SQL is generated in the update statement the just add: var_dump($sql); after the '$allOk = ...' line.

Comment: you are welcome, literally, feel free to ask questions. I may not write code but i will try and provide positive help.